# MutationObserver not firing div display is set to none

Tags: javascript, mutation-observers

I have the following div whose display style changes to none when view is tablet or desktop and would like to detect that change with MutationObserver:

```
<div class="l-off-canvas l-off-canvas--left l-off-canvas--right l-stack l-stack--horse l-hidden@tablet l-hidden@desktop" data-mobile-view>
        <div class="l-grid l-grid--no-gap">
            <div data-component-hook-blog-function="blogColumn" class="l-grid__cell l-grid__cell--1/3 l-grid__cell--1/1@phone" data-blog-mobile-column></div>
        </div>
</div>
```

I tried the following in JS but the MutationObserver does not fire when I resize the viewport from mobile to desktop and vice versa:

```
divMobileArticles = document.querySelector<HTMLElement>('[data-mobile-view]');


const observer = new MutationObserver((mutationRecords) => {
            console.log(mutationRecords); // console.log(the changes)
        });
// observe everything except attributes
        observer.observe(divMobileArticles, {
            attributes: true,
            childList: true, // observe direct children
            subtree: true, // and lower descendants too
            characterDataOldValue: true, // pass old data to callback
        });
```

I also tried observing a much higher ancestor element and adding the attributeFilter to the options but the Observer still does not fire when resizing the viewport.

```
 const observer = new MutationObserver((mutationRecords) => {
            console.log(mutationRecords); // console.log(the changes)
        });
// observe everything except attributes
        observer.observe(this.config.element, {
            attributes: true,
            attributeFilter: ['data-mobile-view'],
            childList: true, // observe direct children
            subtree: true, // and lower descendants too
            characterDataOldValue: true, // pass old data to callback
        });
```

Comment: It's possible the site recreates the entire element or even its parent tree, so you need to observe a [much] higher ancestor element. To limit the reported mutations in this case, add `attributes: ['data-mobile-view']` to the config.

Comment: Thanks @wOxxOm I tried as you suggested but the observer still does not fire.

Comment: Try observing `document.body`. Also what do you mean by "display style changes to none"?

Comment: @wOxxOm Basically this div is rendered or is not rendered depending on the style property display. This is what I like to observe.